# Approaches for "action required" process?

Tags: user-behavior, warnings

I'm struggling a bit with this.

## The scenario

This is a process where users signup, and after that I need to present them with a splash page telling them that, in order to use the service, they need to do some action (in this case, send documents, and after verification, they get a key on their physical mail address, not mail).

Users still can access the admin area, they can perform a wide variety of actions, but they can't make the process go live until they finish the registration process.

While I can see the flaws in the current process, this is the only part that I can't change, so I'm left with a subset of actions to present the user, some of them can be logically dismissed, some can be optional.

## The current approach

The legacy approach is to present a sliding modal, which works fine in terms of calling user's attention, although its copy is really poor and the messaging is kind of restrictive. Furthermore, it's easily dismissed, and as an user, I don't know what happened and why can't I do anything.

## My proposed solution (so far)

Working on a stronger modal alert and keep inline warnings across pages/activities as well as an always visible "super header" in red with a warning icon and a link to the action required. Based in experience on other projects, this is a good approach and I think it will work fine (barring further testing).

## My Problem

While I have figured out the set of actions and elements, I really can't find a message that is informative as well as affirmative and engages the user to use the system, yet letting him/her know they need to perform an action. I'm leaning towards the user of iconography or a quick learning system with drawings. That would be no problem for us, but both the content and the copy are quite diffuse for me right now, really can't figure it out.

Note that while I have more or less an idea on how to lay out information, I'm open to suggestions, and I also understand that different content requires different visual approaches, so please don't be restricted by my proposed solution, because it obviously has issues!

Comment: Can the actual initial message be a link pointing to a larger sent of content / information with specific details.  For instance, "No action can be taken until you have checked your mail" (of course this is just an example)...Display this but have it clickable to an action / page that gives more details.  The details could include information specific to what the user needs to do and how to authenticate.

Comment: This is more or less what I have now, but my concern is that I want the user to engage into using the system, so it's kind of "while we wait for your documents, why don't start working on your project?" Basically avoid any negative message

Comment: so your main goal is to aware the user about the required action?

Comment: no, that's the easy part. What I want is a solution in which the users are aware that they need to perform one or more actions, yet they need to know they can use the system. Furthermore, be encouraged to do it. Basically, I don't want to lose user engagement by adding a barrier, but I have 2 contradictory situations: **users can do what they want / users won't be able to complete anything**. Thus, my metaphor is: *"you can follow all available paths (=actions), just be aware the task won't be 100% completed until you perform the required step(s)"*

Answer (score 1):

Given that the user cannot proceed unless he/she performs an action/set of actions, the use of a constant reminder is a good play.
Also supporting your text content with icons is a good strategy that will assist those users who tend to skip text content.

For the actual content, I would suggest be precise and to the point.

An Example:
In order to use our service/system, you need to complete these steps. We know you are busy but it won't take more than 5 minutes of your time and is super easy. Once done, you wont ever have to go through this again.

Additionally mention that all user information will be safely stored and not shared with any other corporation for any purposes.

Comment: this is quite in line with what I need, although not entirely. +1  in the meanwhile